# OpenMP: what is the difference between "taskloop" and "omp for" performance wise?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

"taskloop" is introduced in OpenMP 4.5. It can take clauses from both loop and task constructs (except depend clause AFAIK).

However, I'm wondering if "taskloop" and "omp for" constructs differ performance wise too.

Comment: When I wonder about that sort of thing I set up a test or two and investigate.  Why don't you ?

Comment: I have done it for one example. But I couldn't test it for every other case. I use gcc for compilation. For some cases, it generates the error "internal compiler error" and for others it compiles fine but compiled program executes sequentially when t has "taskloop" construct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may depends on the actual problem. To parallelize a for loop **omp for** can be faster than **task**s, because it offers several different scheduling scheme for your needs. In my experience (solving a particular problem using clang12 compiler) **omp for** produces a bit faster code than **task**s (on Ryzen 5 7800X).